# SQL Insert Into Where

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO Participant (Password) 
VALUES ('768YcnaDG') 
WHERE ParticipantID = 1048
```

I'm trying to do an insert into SQL command with a where clause. There is an error message that says incorrect syntax near where. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE Participant 
    SET Password = '768YcnaDG'
    WHERE ParticipantID = 1048;
```

`INSERT` adds an entirely new row into the table.  `UPDATE` modifies the values of one or more columns.